# how to solve render problem Path.op() not supported?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, render

How to solve this error:
Render problem
Path.op() not supported

I tried to force refresh layout, restart, update Android Studio, stop antivirus for a while, but the problem is still there.

Surprisingly I am able to compile and run the app, but how to get rid of this error?

I am using:

- Android Studio 3.5.3
- Android SDK Tools 29.0.2
- Android SDK Platform Android 10.0 (Q) Android SDK Platform 29
- Default OpenJDK Platform binary

to reproduce the error:

- Create new Android project with empty activity
- replace the layout with the following layout:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/parent_view"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity"
      android:background="@android:color/white">


      <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
          android:id="@+id/appbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

      </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

      <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
          android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:clipToPadding="false"
          android:scrollbars="none"
          android:scrollingCache="true"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

              <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                  app:cardElevation="2dp">

                  <RelativeLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                      <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                          android:id="@+id/pager"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="250dp"
                          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                          android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                      <RelativeLayout
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                          android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                          android:paddingRight="12dp"
                          android:paddingTop="14dp">

                          <LinearLayout
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:orientation="vertical">

                              <TextView
                                  android:id="@+id/title"
                                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                  android:text="Title is going here"
                                  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                                  android:textColor="@android:color/white" />





                              <TextView
                                  android:id="@+id/brief"
                                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                  android:text=" Location"
                                  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"  />


                          </LinearLayout>

                          <LinearLayout
                              android:id="@+id/layout_dots"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                              android:layout_gravity="end"
                              android:gravity="center"
                              android:orientation="horizontal" />


                      </RelativeLayout>

                  </RelativeLayout>

              </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

              <View
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="16dp" />

              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_margin="16dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

                  <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Description"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                  <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                      android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                      android:text="very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum very_long_lorem_ipsum "
                      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>


              </LinearLayout>

              <View
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="8dp" />


          </LinearLayout>

      </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. The reason is, that the new versions of Material Components are bundled with this bug. So, I tried replacing the version in the Gradle build script with the version that supports `Path.op()`.

**So, the only thing you have to do is replace the dependency in your Gradle build script with this one:**

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'

Comment: Worked for me as well. Button icons were not showing on layouts, this solved the issue.

Comment: The current latest version: `'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'` seems to have fixed the bug

Comment: Solution: use new layout rendering engine. For this go to Settings -> Experimental -> Check "Use new Layout Rendering Engine"

Answer (score 11):

Problem solved by replacing the material component implementation in Gradle Build ( at App level )

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05
```

to

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the Experimental Rendering Engine, which solved the problem for me. First Suggested by [Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2926237/carlos).

Here is how to do it in android studio.

***Go to File > Settings***

[image: Go to File > Settings]

Now the settings window will show up.

 Go to the **Experimental** tab and check/tick ***Use new Layout Rendering Engine***

[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into the same problem yesterday. Mine got to do with the

> com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

component.
I do not know exactly why, but adding `android:background="..."` solves it.

Answer (score 4):

A little late but

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'`

works correctly, so no need to downgrade to alpha02 anymore.

Comment: not worked for me. already with alpha-06 and same problem after clearing, rebuilding.

Comment: Just tried `1.2.0-rc01` and the bug is still there.

Comment: The current latest version: `'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'` seems to be working correctly

Answer (score 3):

Using the new Layout Rendering Engine helped fixing my problem. Go to Settings -> Experimental -> Use new Layout Rendering Engine

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to have been resolved in the latest version of material components which is currently:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The problem improved when I run the application. I think the problem will be improved when you clear and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

anyone going through this problem just downgrade or upgrade you material design dependency
to

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

seems to be more stable in terms of rendering especially if you are using android studio V3.4 and above.
I miss eclipse sometimes

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue while using chip,it's not visible in layout editor. resolved it by changing

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```

to

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "ImageView"s inside your make sure their XML code is like this.

Your default generated could be like below.
[Wrong XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBJOZ.png)

**Change (tools:srcCompat="@drawable/img_avatar") to (android:src="@drawable/img_avatar")** like below
[Correct XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyDln.png)

I think it will fix that problem for you. Thank you.

Additional Details:-
[My Android Studio Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYDBE.png)
[My Gradle Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldKBM.png)

I ran into this problem when I tried to display a PNG in a ImgView.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating: version 1.3.0-rc01 is already launched. You can use

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-rc01'`

Comment: Solution:
use new layout rendering engine. For this go to Settings -> Experimental -> Check "Use new Layout Rendering Engine"

Answer (score 0):

Just don't define version:
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material'
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only after removing fastScroll settings from androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

changing the dependency worked for me:

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'`