# Material edit text not rendering in android studio editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

My android sudio design editor don't render material TextInputLayouts. I already tried invalidate caches. Every other element is rendering correct also other material elements

```
                   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ti"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:hint="@string/street_number">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:text="@{vm.user.streetnumber}" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change in build.gradle

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'`

It seems newer versions are not rendered correctly.

See:[how to solve render problem Path.op() not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809654/how-to-solve-render-problem-path-op-not-supported)

Comment: I was using version `1.2.0-alpha05` and it's not rendering well. Thanks

Comment: This library is updated. Use latest version: 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-beta01'  or newer

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the theme in the layout builder to match the one of your app.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, Default is Material.Light.NoActionBar. Nevertheless I also tried other themes, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

in my case Update Android Studio, problem fix

Answer (score 0):

Show all warnings in XML and press to recommendation that wrapped with blue and press modern rendering feature and Restart Android Studio. You can switch off this feature.