# My code doesn't render the drawer. "Path.op() not supported"

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I encounter this kind of problem. I have to put a drawer toggle in my application but when I run it, it doesn't render the drawer. Does anyone have idea on kind of error. Because when I check my code it doesn't have any error. By the way I don't know where in my code has to do something on this.

```
package com.core.core_techapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class Nav extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    TextView navName, navEmail;
    ImageView navImage;


    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navtech);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer_layout,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


        navName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.customerName);
        navEmail = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.customerEmail);
        navImage = (ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //GET NAME AND EMAIL
        GoogleSignInAccount acct;
        acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (acct != null) {

            //This process is to fetch data from Gmail accounts that are signed in with the device.

            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            //String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
            //String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
            Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

            navName.setText(personName);
            navEmail.setText(personEmail);

            Glide.with(this).load(String.valueOf(personPhoto)).into(navImage);

        }

    }

    private void signOut() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(Nav.this, "Signed out successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_complaint:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ComplaintFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new AboutFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_map:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MapFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                signOut();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve render problem Path.op() not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809654/how-to-solve-render-problem-path-op-not-supported)