# How to make rounded corners for Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, material-components-android, android-shapedrawable

I've seen other answers and they all apply to actionbars not toolbars and they require creating new shapes.

Is there a simple way to do this using the `styles.xml`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't what you are looking for because it is not with a xml.
Currently (`1.2.0-beta01` and `1.3.0-alpha01`) the `Toolbar` or `MaterialToolbar` don't support a `shapeAppearance` style as other components in the `styles.xml`.
But you can use in any case the [`ShapeAppearanceModel`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) provided by the Material Components Library.

In your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    ..>
```

Then just apply the `ShapeAppearanceModel` with rounded corners:

```
    float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius); //32dp
    MaterialToolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  
    MaterialShapeDrawable materialShapeDrawable = (MaterialShapeDrawable)toolbar.getBackground();
    materialShapeDrawable.setShapeAppearanceModel(materialShapeDrawable.getShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
            .build());
```

[image]

Comment: How to fix this error: "android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable"

Comment: It shows up at the third line of the second code snippet

Comment: @User104163 Are you using a `MaterialToolbar` or `androidx.Toolbar` ?

Comment: oh sh*t. I need to concentrate more :)

Comment: Hi I just have one more problem. I'm doing round corner for bottom left and bottom right but it's appearing like this as if pushed to the up-right position: https://i.ibb.co/wWz6VYB/Untitled.png

Comment: @User104163 Using `.setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
      .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)` I am not able to replicate your issue. Are you using a custom layout inside the `Toolbar`?

Comment: No but I do get this error: Render problem: Path.op() not supported . Could this be why my toolbar is turning out this way?

Comment: @User104163 check also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809654/how-to-solve-render-problem-path-op-not-supported). Use the version 1.2.0-beta01 or 1.1.0

Comment: I got the fix: it's to replace the material components dependency in Gradle with the newer version: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'`

Comment: ah, we found the fix at the same time :)

Comment: The toolbar is still drawn the same incorrect way despite fixing the "Render problem" error. I guess the problem lies somewhere else :(

Comment: What could the problem be?

Comment: I found the problem. It's when I use `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` to add the title and options menu to the toolbar. This method doesn't seem to work well with rounded corners. How do you add items to the toolbar?

Comment: It can work with both, the toolbar using `toolbar.setTitle`, `toolbar.inflateMenu`) and the `setSupportActionBar()` using `getSupportActionBar().setTitle` and overriding the  `onCreateOptionsMenu`. You have to check the styles you are using.

Comment: oof. I was using `android:theme="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"` thinking it's the same as using `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary`. That's where the error was. Sorry I keep giving you such a headache :)

Comment: Hi sorry I swear this is the absolute last question: Is there a way to center the Title in the middle of the toolbar? Without creating a TextView

Comment: This answer is good and indeed it works. However, it is a problem when using a Toolbar inside an AppBarLayout. The background gets the desired shape, but the shadow is still shown as rectangular

Comment: @BamsBamx Maybe you should try to set `elevation` to `0dp` for AppBarLayout

Answer (score 3):

Create a drawable resource (e.g curvedToolbar.XML):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmls:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/red/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

        <corners android:radius= "20dp"/>

    </shape>
```

Add it to your toolbar like this:

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
      ......
      android:background= "@drawable/curvedToolbar"
   />
```