# Activity Layout goes blank when switched to Material Design components

Tags: android, material-design, mdc-components

Problem :
There was no problem when app was using

> Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

But was not using any MDC elements in Layout like (TextInputLayout etc).

Then i replaced `Editext` with `TextInputLayout` and Button with Material Button.

Now here the problem comes.

When i run my app, i see the screen goes blank. Just pure white.

I checked Layout isses.
I found there're 7 warnings and 2 errors(Render problem).

The Render problems are as -

> 1. Path.op() not supported. (As was it suggests i refreshed the layout many times. Doesn't work)
> 2. java.awt.geom.IllegalPathStateException: missing initial move to in path definition

This is what i have tried -

1. Downgrading my MDC dependency ([how to solve render problem Path.op() not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809654/how-to-solve-render-problem-path-op-not-supported))
2. Clean project, rebuild and restart Android studio

Please help me to solve this strange issue.
I want to use MDC in my project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should first make use of the Bridge then, gradually override the parent theme attributes based on your requirement design.

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
 android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
```

Then under style.xml. it would like something like

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>

    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/BlueToolbar</item>
</style>
```

try referring [reference](https://medium.com/over-engineering/setting-up-a-material-components-theme-for-android-fbf7774da739) , [reference](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started)

Simple solution is make your theme extend a Bridge theme :) I hope this helps